# Process n objects each time by condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next object struct:

```
{
1698452536:Object {url: "1", isProcessed: false}
1701673991:Object {url: "2", isProcessed: false}
1717724454:Object {url: "3", isProcessed: false}
1756233961:Object {url: "4", isProcessed: false}
1797093325:Object {url: "5", isProcessed: false}
1857721095:Object {url: "6", isProcessed: false}
2095153396:Object {url: "7", isProcessed: false}
2098466246:Object {url: "8", isProcessed: false}
2131427779:Object {url: "9", isProcessed: false}
89975:Object {url: "10", isProcessed: false}
21591836:Object {url: "11", isProcessed: false}
80794211:Object {url: "12", isProcessed: false}
116460496:Object {url: "13", isProcessed: false}
159798435:Object {url: "14", isProcessed: false}
223366448:Object {url: "15", isProcessed: false}
361352239:Object {url: "16", isProcessed: false}
498790092:Object {url: "17", isProcessed: false}
508072650:Object {url: "18", isProcessed: false}
514973525:Object {url: "19", isProcessed: false}
560440401:Object {url: "20", isProcessed: false}
}
```

I need to process five inner objects each time and only after first five is completed take another five.
Is there is a way to do such implementation?

**UPDATE:**

I`d tried next code in order to transform object to chunked array, but how to call bulk by bulk async and only after full bulk is succeed take another?

```
chunkArray(Object.values(images),5).forEach((array)=>{});
function chunkArray(array, groupsize) {
var sets = [],
    chunks, i = 0;
chunks = array.length / groupsize;

while (i < chunks) {
    sets[i] = array.splice(0, groupsize);
    i++;
}
return sets;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "five by five"? Five objects each time or the fifth index, tenth index, etc.?

Comment: Five objects each time

Comment: **asynchronous** processing?

Comment: @le_m yes async

Answer (score 1):

Here is a skeleton of what you will need. I tried to name the functions and variables in a way that it could be self explaining.

```js
'use strict';

let toProcess = {
 '1698452536': { url: "1", isProcessed: false },
 '1701673991': { url: "2", isProcessed: false },
 '1717724454': { url: "3", isProcessed: false },
 '1756233961': { url: "4", isProcessed: false },
 '1797093325': { url: "5", isProcessed: false },
 '1857721095': { url: "6", isProcessed: false },
 '2095153396': { url: "7", isProcessed: false },
 '2098466246': { url: "8", isProcessed: false },
 '2131427779': { url: "9", isProcessed: false },
 '89975': { url: "10", isProcessed: false },
 '21591836': { url: "11", isProcessed: false },
 '80794211': { url: "12", isProcessed: false },
 '116460496': { url: "13", isProcessed: false },
 '159798435': { url: "14", isProcessed: false },
 '223366448': { url: "15", isProcessed: false },
 '361352239': { url: "16", isProcessed: false },
 '498790092': { url: "17", isProcessed: false },
 '508072650': { url: "18", isProcessed: false },
 '514973525': { url: "19", isProcessed: false },
 '560440401': { url: "20", isProcessed: false }
};

let howManyItemsInConcurrency = 5;
stackProcessing(toProcess, howManyItemsInConcurrency);

function stackProcessing(stack, concurrency){
 let objsToProcess = Object.keys(stack).filter(objKey => !stack[objKey].isProcessed).slice(0, concurrency);
 if(!objsToProcess.length){
  return console.log('Finish!');
 }

 let objsBeingProcessed = objsToProcess.map(objKey => objProcessing(stack[objKey]));
 Promise.all(objsBeingProcessed)
  .then(result => {
   console.log('result', result);
   stackProcessing(stack, concurrency);
  });
}


function objProcessing(obj){
 console.log(`Processing URL: ${obj.url}`);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Simulating some async processing happening
  setTimeout(() => {
   obj.isProcessed = true;
   resolve(obj);
  }, 1000);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys to get all the object's keys as an array, and then you can do your solution for array:

```
var objs = {
    1698452536:Object {url: "1", isProcessed: false}
    1701673991:Object {url: "2", isProcessed: false}
    1717724454:Object {url: "3", isProcessed: false}
    1756233961:Object {url: "4", isProcessed: false}
    1797093325:Object {url: "5", isProcessed: false}
    1857721095:Object {url: "6", isProcessed: false}
    2095153396:Object {url: "7", isProcessed: false}
    2098466246:Object {url: "8", isProcessed: false}
    2131427779:Object {url: "9", isProcessed: false}
    89975:Object {url: "10", isProcessed: false}
    21591836:Object {url: "11", isProcessed: false}
    80794211:Object {url: "12", isProcessed: false}
    116460496:Object {url: "13", isProcessed: false}
    159798435:Object {url: "14", isProcessed: false}
    223366448:Object {url: "15", isProcessed: false}
    361352239:Object {url: "16", isProcessed: false}
    498790092:Object {url: "17", isProcessed: false}
    508072650:Object {url: "18", isProcessed: false}
    514973525:Object {url: "19", isProcessed: false}
    560440401:Object {url: "20", isProcessed: false}
};

var keys = Object.keys(objs);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 5) {
    // Do something on every five keys      
}
```

Comment: I have to call urls async via node request or http.get

Comment: That's not JSON; that's just an object. JSON is a string format.

Comment: The value is not JSON, but all the values are inside a JSON. And if I understand it right, he/she wants to get five objects every time from this JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The following promise-based solution transfers batches of size n = 5 items to your asynchronous callback function and continues as soon as the callback signals completion:

```js
// Process items in batches of size n via callback cb:
function process(items, n, cb, offset = 0) {
  if (offset >= items.length) return;
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cb(items.slice(offset, offset + n), resolve, reject);
  }).then(() => process(items, n, cb, offset + n));
}

// Example:
let items = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

process(items, 5, (batch, resolve) => {
  console.log("processing " + batch);
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000); // Async processig...
});
```

In case your asynchronous callback can only handle one item at a time, you might want to create 5 promises and wait till [all have resolved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) before recursing to the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Diego ZoracKy, he's answer provide me the basis to solve this issue.

```
let processImages = () => {
                    let itemToDo = Object.values(images).filter((item) => { return !item.isProcessed }).slice(0, 5);
                    if (itemToDo.length) {
                        async.map(itemToDo, (arrayItem, callback) => {
                                try {
                                    imagesize(arrayItem.url).then((result) => {
                                        return callback(null, result);
                                    }).catch(function(err) {
                                        return callback(err);

                                } catch (e) {
                                    return callback(err);
                                }
                            },
                            (errors, results) => {
                                results.forEach((result) => {
                                  ...
                                });
                                if (errors) {                                       
               console.log('error', '!!!!!!!!!Exception was caught!!!!!! ');
                                }
                                processImages();
                            }
                        )
                    } else {
                        //CONTINUE TO NEXT URL
                        }
                }
                //Invoke process images function first time
            processImages();
```